# Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Method get_site_editor_type does not exist in... on line 45

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I have tried everything, I have replaced and added  a new code based on what people suggested but nothing has improved. I am still having the same error.

Nothing has working so far... I would appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: Can you explain briefly what you tried and share here with screenshot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open this file:
`wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/theme-builder/documents/theme-document.php`

Add this code to line 46 of that file:

`if (method_exists($class_name, "get_site_editor_type")) {`

then close the `if` in line 54 with `}`.

The final result looks this:

```php
if (method_exists($class_name, "get_site_editor_type")) {
    $reflection = new \ReflectionClass( $class_name );
    $method = $reflection->getMethod( 'get_site_editor_type' );

    // It's own method, use it.
    if ( $class_name === $method->class ) {
        return static::get_site_editor_type();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an elementor plugin to the latest version but in your current theme or some other plugins having the old version code which is not compatible with the latest update. Some classes or functions may be deprecated and they have alternatives in the new version. Do one thing if you have a backup available then restore the elementor or plugin to the old version. Else update the code which is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen on several sites and I comment out the line and it works fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Goto this file path `wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/theme-builder/documents/theme-document.php` and comment the line#48 i.e. `$method = $reflection->getMethod( 'get_site_editor_type' );`